# Add a prefix to every line in a multiline Text Input in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, textinput, flutter-text

I wanted to know if there was a way of adding a prefix (like "- ") to every line in a multiline Text Input in Flutter.

**For example:**

Hello

World!

**Would become:**

-Hello

-World!

**This is my code:**

```
TextField(
  maxLines: null,
  controller: _elementsController,
  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 18.0,
  ),
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
    labelText: 'Elements',
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can add a `-` everytime a new line is created.

Add this in your initState(),

```
final prefix = '-';
_elementsContoller.addListener(() {
  if(_elementsController.text.endsWith('\n')) {
    // Add the prefix everytime a new line is created
    _elementsController.text +=  prefix;
  }
}
```

If these changes should be made after the input,

```
text.replaceAll('\n', '\n$prefix');
```

Comment: It gives me an error that says: The argument type 'Null Function(dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()'

Comment: The listener doesn't get the text argument. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the code but this kind of solution doesn't apply properly to the solution I'm looking for. The prefix (when the text changes) is added at the end of the textfield, and the cursor is left at the beginning.

Comment: If there was a way of making the cursor stay at the end of the textfield it would completely solve the problem.