# How to add prefix widget on every new line in textfield in flutter?

Tags: flutter, textview

I want to know if it's possible to add prefix widget to each line in Multiline Textfield widget in flutter. If yes then how ?

I have looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63211954/add-a-prefix-to-every-line-in-a-multiline-text-input-in-flutter)

However the answer to that question would only work with prefix text.
What if I want to attach icon widget or any other widget ?

Comment: im not sure but i think you need to use of ListTile widget

Comment: @Shubham_Narkhede you mean for each line I can create new ListTile widget ?